# call .net dll from wxpython

Tags: python, .net, wxpython, python.net

I have an event handler in wxpython which is supposed to call a .net dll and use it. I searched for a solution on the net and failed to find it. Could you please anyone let me know the way to do it? 
I've found that ironpython is the way but have no idea about it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did install active state python 2.7 and tried calling .net dll through clr and i'm not able to do it.It says 'no module named clr'. I could able to call the dll's using ironpython which i do not want to!

Comment: import clr
    clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("/path/to/mydll")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: AddReferenceToFileAndPath
>>> help(clr)
Help on module clr:

NAME
    clr

FILE
    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\clr.pyd

DATA
    AddReference = <CLRModuleFunction 'AddReference'>
    FindAssembly = <CLRModuleFunction 'FindAssembly'>
    ListAssemblies = <CLRModuleFunction 'ListAssemblies'>
    getPreload = <CLRModuleFunction 'getPreload'>
    setPreload = <CLRModuleFunction 'setPreload'>

Answer (score 1):

Install pythonnet either using PIP or downloading zip files.

Copy all the pythonnet files(clr.pyd,nPython,nPython.pdb,Python.Runtime.dll,Python.Runtime.pdb) into *c:\python27\Lib\site-packages* folder

Now import clr from active state python shell and add reference to .net dll(do not add .dll extention in the path) and call the object and methods of that dll.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('c:\my\path\to\dllfile')
```